# Android, should all code be written in an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox

I am more familiar with iOS development than Android and I am wondering if all code should be written in an Activity rather than having a "model" class.

I have a couple screens each with a few checkboxes and I want them all to behave the same on click, I am trying to figure out how I would do this without writing repeating code in each activity. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe subclass some custom parent activity?

Comment: What screens are you talking about? Fragments or separate activities?

Comment: All the OOP jazz still applies as Android development is done in Java, a fully capable OOP language so you don't _need_ to radically alter your development practices, the idiomatic ways to do things do change though.

Comment: @Simas Separate activities, but I'm still unsure of how to implement the same functionality for each activity. Should I just implement the functionality in one activity then have the rest make an object of that activity to use it's onclick method?

Answer (score 2):

No you should not. If you are familiar with java, think of an activity as a extension of main with OO added.
In your particular example you can create a class with a method like:
`<MethodName>(View <checkboxClickedName>){ //your code here }`. and then add this to the checkbox in the XML `android:onClick="<MethodName>"`, you may need the full package path (e.g. com.example.app.)

Note: if some of the commands/objects you need are only available within an activity you should create this in an calss that `extends Activity` or preferably within the running activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a base class that extends activity that contains the methods that you want executed on click (either implemented or abstract). Use this new base class instead of activity when making new activities. In the layout xml, you can set the onclick of each checkbox to be the method in the base activity you want executed.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to use a single activity and switch fragments as if they were your screens. Then, the activity could simply implement the listener interface that the fragments would re-use.

---

Since you have multiple activities this becomes a little bit harder. To *really* re-use a single listener, I can think of a single (not so beautiful) option. Create a static listener and lazy load it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static View.OnClickListener sCheckboxClickListener;

    public static View.OnClickListener getCheckboxClickListener() {
        if (sCheckboxClickListener == null) {
            sCheckboxClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Work with v
                }
            };
        }
        return sCheckboxClickListener;
    }

}
```

And in each of your activities call:

```
findViewById(R.id.checkbox1)
            .setOnClickListener(MainActivity.getCheckboxClickListener());
```